# what is the difference between series and tournament in tennis?

Tags: tennis, tournaments

I am working on the ATP  tennis matches dataset and I have a series column which contains International, ATP250, Grand Slam  etc... and a tournament column which contains Wimbledon, Lyon Open  etc...
I want to know the difference between them?
which is more general than the other.
also which one of them is more relevant to the player to make him play 100% in that match is it the type of series or type of tournament?
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Series" is more general than "Tournament".  A tournament is held on a week or two in a particular location.  A series is a series of tournaments - for example, the [ATP Tour 250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Tour_250) is a series of 39 tournaments (as of the date this answer was written).  The series to some extent reflects the level of the tournaments in the series - ATP250 is the lowest level, Grand Slam is the highest.

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A series, is just a combination of tournaments. Tournaments are the usual competitions, they're 1 or 2 weeks long, where players are seeded at the beginning of the event go against each other.

A series is just some of theses events together. It could indicate tournaments played at a certain level like [ATP Tour 250 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Tour_250), [ATP Tour 500 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Tour_500), [ATP Tour Masters 1000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Tour_Masters_1000). Or tournaments held by the same governing body like the [US Open Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Open_Series).